# How to sort group of nodes in xsl?

Tags: xslt

below is the xml

```
<products>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>30</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>10</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pencil</item> 
            <price>5</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>15</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>23</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Pencil</item> 
            <price>8</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>5</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>10</price>
        </items>        
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>24</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Paper Box</item> 
            <price>7</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>4</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>13</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1002</supplierid>
        <totalprice>26</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Sharpner Box</item> 
            <price>7</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>4</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>15</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
</products>
```

I need output like below using xsl 1.0

```
SupplierID       Items                  TotalPrice
1001             Pencil,Pen,Bag             23
1001             Paper Box,Pen,Bag          24    
1002             Sharpner Box,Pen,Bag       26
1001             Pencil,Pen,Bag             30
```

1. Total Price  ASC
2. items of different node in one line

hoping your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet transforming your XML to HTML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SupplierID</th>
          <th>Items</th>
          <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="supplier">
          <xsl:sort select="totalprice" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="supplier">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="supplierid"/></td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item"/>
      </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalprice"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You only need to correct tabs (formatting)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">SupplierID      Items               TotalPrice
</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="supplier">
<xsl:sort order="ascending"  select="totalprice/text()" />

<xsl:value-of select="supplierid/text()" />
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">            </xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="items">
    <xsl:value-of select="item/text()" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">        </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="totalprice/text()" />
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
</xsl:text>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```